# Nginx and unicorn

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I have 2 aplications, each one running on unicorn.
I'd like to use nginx as a front end for each of those application.
For each nginx / unicorn pair I would then use a dedicated unix socket.
To do so, do I need to have to instance of nginx or can I use 2 virtual hosts ?

Comment: no way a windows admin could survive running an app called unicorn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need multiple nginx instances, you could specify multiple [`proxy_pass`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) with different unix sockets or defined multiple [`upstream`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#upstream) sections.